# How to set some keys to be pressed automatically and alternativly?

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard

I need some pattern of keys be press automatically in a loop.

For example `windows Key+prt sc` then `up button` and wait for 500ms and anew...

I need to this hundreds of time by a loop

Comment: [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DavidPostill mentioned in a comment, [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) is an awesome tool that can do exactly that.

As an example the simple loop below *should* do what you want (I havent' installed AHK on this machine), assuming that the window you want this to happen in is active when you press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

```
^!s::
Loop 500 {
    Send {LWin down}{PrintScreen}{LWin up}
    Send {Up}
    Sleep 500
}
```

Put this in a file named `hotkey.ahk` and run it using autohotkey.

Alternatively there is also [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) which has a subtly different syntax but can achieve much the same.

Comment: I'd say the syntax difference isn't really subtle, though I suppose it's all relative. Perhaps for this small script it might be.